# Elm Generator Int -> List Int

Tags: elm

I want to get `List` out of `Generator`

```
intList : Generator (List Int)
intList =
    list 5 (int 0 100)
```

How could I now get a list out of it?

Comment: You can't because the function that returns a list of 5 random numbers would not be pure. Can you say more about what you want to achieve and we can help find the idiomatic approach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get a random list out of `Generator` because Elm functions are always pure. The only possibility to get a list is to use a *command*.

A command is a way to tell Elm runtime to do some impure operation. In your case, you can tell it to generate a random list of integers. Then it will return back the result of that operation as an argument of the `update` function.

To send Elm runtime a command to generate a random value, you can use the function `Random.generate`:

```
generate : (a -> msg) -> Generator a -> Cmd msg
```

You already have `Generator a` (your `intList`), so you need to provide a function `a -> msg`. This function should wrap `a` (`List Int` in your case) into a *message*.

The final code should be something like that:

```
type Msg =
    RandomListMsg (List Int)
  | ... other types of messages here

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model = case msg of
    ... -> ( model, Random.generate RandomListMsg intList)
    RandomListMsg yourRandomList -> ...
```

If you don't know about *messages* and *models* yet, you should probably get acquainted with the [Elm architecture](https://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/) first.

Comment: Ended up solving it like this. But I don't understand why I couldnt just run `Random.generate intList` that would return the list, how would this break the `pure function` concept?

Comment: @MihkelL. Pure functions must always return the same values. Your function will return different lists every time, so it cannot be pure.

Comment: What is wrong with this language i don't want cmd msg i want a simple int im trying to get an int for ages from the int function.

Answer (score 4):

You can provide your own seed value to [`Random.step`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Random#step), which will return a tuple containing a list and the next seed value. This retains purity because you will always get the same result when you pass the same seed.

```
Random.step intList (Random.initialSeed 123)
    |> Tuple.first

-- will always yield [69,0,6,93,2]
```

The answer given by @ZhekaKozlov is typically how you generate random values in an application, but it uses `Random.step` under the hood with the current time used as the initial seed.

Comment: I do think this example answers better to my actual question. But the other answer maybe shows more "best practice" also. Thanks for this answer ;)